# Handling Very Large Numbers of Swift Classes

Tags: ios, swift

Targeting iOS 9+, with Swift 3

My app makes use of hundreds (and potentially thousands) of Swift classes.

Each class is responsible for drawing a specific piece of vector artwork. The artwork is created in Sketch, and exported as a Swift class using the PaintCode plugin. Each class can be quite complex and lengthy, with a lot of data. The class file is then fed to an automated command-line tool that writes app-specific functionality in to the file, allowing the art to become interactive and flexible. The resulting Swift file is added to the app's Xcode project.

As Swift does not allow for Objective-C style dynamic loading/creation of classes by name (*feel free to correct*), my app adds the processed Swift class to a lookup table of drawing classes. When the app needs to draw a specific piece of artwork, the class lookup table is read, the relevant class is returned, and is then used to draw the art.

I am concerned that this approach may not be viable once the project ramps up to full-scale production, at which point hundreds or thousands of classes will be generated. Possible problems include:

- compilation times
- code size
- app loading times
- Xcode/SourceKitServer stability/meltdowns

To that end, I'd like advice on overcoming possible problems before they become deal-breakers.

Specifically:

Q. what approach should I take to minimise re-compilation? Is it viable to bundle groups of classes together in Frameworks or other mechanisms?

Q. same thing for code size and app loading times. How can I group my code so I can more easily lazy-load groups of classes on demand? Would Frameworks help solve these problems?

Any advice, or other considerations I may have missed, is appreciated.

**[Edit - many months and a lot of work later]**

For the reasons outlined above, I **abandoned** attempts to us PaintCode or other art-as-code solutions.

Although these products are perfectly fine for small numbers of art pieces, the system does not scale well to large production, and certainly not for Swift and the state of its support in Xcode 8.

Instead, I adopted a file-based approach where artwork is prepared in Sketch, and layers are marked-up with drawing information. These are exported as SVGs. The engine loads an SVG **on-demand**, parses it, and the mark-up is used to indicate/direct app-specific logic and drawing. Due to the amount of work involved, this is not viable for small numbers of art pieces -- stick to PaintCode instead -- but once done it allows a great amount of flexibility and speed, without all the Xcode and sourcekitservice crashes.

This approach allows the art assets to be wrangled like they normally are: grouped in folders, loaded-on-demand, cached, released etc.

Comment: You neglected to mention a couple of things. First, is this a macOS or iOS app? Remember, there's a a "soft" barrier of 100MB for iOS. Second, what is your roadmap for Swift 4 and beyond? I understand most of the reasons behind your current design, but wonder if there's better ways of doing what you want. Frameworks **can** help overcome some scalability problems, but in your case? Not so much. Maybe storing things in a DB accessible via a web service....

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. (The question is tagged iOS.) I don't have a roadmap for Swift 4, as I don't know what Swift 4 will entail. I do have the option of going back to Obj-C via PaintCode, as Joe suggests. The problem  with the code is not so much a matter of storage -- the files could simply be stored in the app bundle, compressed if necessary -- but rather of how to present them to Swift. In Obj-C we could get a class by name, but since we can't do that in Swift, I can't grab the code from file or a DB. Regards.

Comment: Tagged iOS maybe, but the tone clearly focuses on Swift. :-) In that case, I'd accept Joe's answer - Swift isn't able to handle this sort of thing without wasting too much of your time. Peace.

Comment: @dfd For the record, I originally put "iOS" as the first word in the title. But it was removed by an editor, presumably because the 'iOS" tag was preferred SO form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for swift, but given the constraints you mention, objc is probably your tool for this type of task. Alternately you could come up with a scripting solution. A couple thoughts:

1. You should rasterize your art: Why'd you code it? The platform, and every technology you mention is an apple technology, it therefore helps to use their apps as guides: every apple app utilizes either built in controls, or an overwhelming number of rasterized graphics. (examples include: Logic Studio, Window Server (Aqua), garage band, Calendar, etc.) this is because bitmap manipulation is FAST. The millions of `UIBezier`s in your thousands of classes are a thousand times more complex and could trash your performance because all that math would have to be done on the cpu as opposed to simple bitmap stretches on the gpu. Apple has discussed this at length in cocoa sessions.
2. The Swift runtime isn't mature enough to handle code unloading. You can ostensibly call `dlopen()` on a swift dylib, and it should work, but it would be very different than working with real swift classes. Swift doesn't have the dynamicism to support this. You also can not call `dlclose()`. Apple's Swift Bug Tracker explicitly says `dlclose` is not supported. (In fact, they say they won't support it!)  So if you really have thousands of huge classes, once they're loaded, you wouldn't be able to reliably unload them. In swift, therefore you can't solve the problem like this.
3. If you insist on doing things this way, you ought to investigate offloading CGGraphicsContext work to other threads right from the get go, because you're going to have to manage quite a bit of work that is designed to happen on the main thread. I doubt paint code emit the right code to handle this case.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  (1) I am well aware of the benefits of bitmaps (I was a game developer for many years, and have written a few engines in that time). However, real-time manipulation of vector art allows for features impossible in bitmap systems. Yes, the vectors get rendered to bitmaps and then composited but interactive-vector based systems are very desirable. See PaintCode examples. (2) I agree that Objective-C would be more flexible. I may have to revert to it, if performance does become an issue. Thanks you.

Comment: To clarify: think of  type rendering-systems. Modern systems store and manipulate glyphs as vectors. Operations can be performed on them with ease. Then, as required, individual glyphs are rasterised, cached, displayed. My use-case is rather like that. Handling the graphics at the bitmap level would be like storing typography as a series of bitmaps, instead of, say, TrueType.